# Validation on load

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form with input box.

```js
angular.module('main', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {

    }
  ]);
```

```css
.red-border {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="main">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form name="frm" novalidate="novalidate">
      <input type="text" required name="myname" ng-class="{'red-border':frm.myname.$error.$invalid}" />
      <br>{{frm | json}}
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the input box to be in red border at the beginning, since it's already empty, but it doesn't make it red on load.
When I test it like this: `ng-class="{'red-box':true}"` it does work.

What is the best practice to make it triggered at the very beginning, or do I have to do all workarounds?

Thanks

**Edit:**

here is my code snippet.
https://jsfiddle.net/Ingeeg/afm7rhsw/8/

Comment: I highly doubt you are using angular 1.0.3 in any production application, but that is what you included in that fiddle.  you should update the fiddle to the *actual* version you are using, before trying to present it as a [mcve].

Comment: Note that examples must be accompanied by code in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: I made a correction to my question. Thanks

Comment: it should be frm.myname.$invalid. [formName][inputName].$invalid that's the way.

Comment: either way the value `$invalid` is false at the beginning in  `{{frm | json}}`. It begins to change only after interaction with the form

Comment: You can just use the `$invalid` flag on the form: `ng-class="{'red-border':frm.$invalid}"`. Apart from that, angular only evaluates inputs with the `ng-model` directive. See [this working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afm7rhsw/9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular only evaluates inputs with the `ng-model` directive:

```
<form name="frm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" required name="myname"
           ng-model="myModel"
           ng-class="{'red-border':frm.myname.$invalid}" />
</form>
```

See [this working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afm7rhsw/10/)

Comment: Thanks. `frm.myname.$invalid` also can be used. `ng-model` was a necessary part